# Security implemention in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm implementing some asp.net application in .NET Framework 1.1. Within that application I want to implement some security policy like as follows

1. When user login to the system, and copies the url and paste it into other browser, then that new browser should redirect to him on login page.
2. When user is browsing application, copy the current url, logout, paste the url to a new browser then he should be redirected to the login page.

Please help me implement this type of security in asp.net 1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set session variable on login page. Create one function "IsLoggedIn" and in this function check whether value is set for session or not. If not than user is not logged in and show login page. This function you need to copy on each page's page_load event. Make sure you reset session or make it null once user logs out.

```
public static bool IsLoggedIn()
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] != null && Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"]) != String.Empty)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

if (!IsLoggedIn())
            {
                Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Url.ToString());
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx" + "?ReturnUrl=" + (Request.FilePath));
            }
```

Comment: Hi Ashish thanx for this its work fine....i want to implement browser session means if i copy url & paste in new browser without logout previous session i start new browser then it should redirect to login page how i will implement this..? plz help

Comment: This issue is specific with the browser. If you open same in new tab than it will persist session value. Some browser allows to persist session value in new window. Let you know if I find useful link ASAP.